# Help with philosophical interpretation of the movie 'V for Vendetta'

Tags: nietzsche, marx

I am having a hard time with my essay on the film, 'V for Vendetta'. I am required to analyze the film from the perspective of two masters of suspicion, Marx and Nietzsche, but I cannot reach a conclusion in order to answer my essay question which is,

> Considering V’s actions in the film, does he try to transform the structures of society according to Marx’s ideas or Nietzsche’s?

Hope you can give me a little help in order to guide me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at a [Marxist analysis of V for Vendetta by Couzens](http://umt-understandingmarxisttheory.blogspot.com/2014/05/a-critical-analysis-on-v-for-vendetta.html) and at [Struggles With Philosophy blog](http://struggleswithphilosophy.blogspot.com/2008/05/return-to-v-for-vendetta.html) for a Nieztschean perspective. [Call](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/dc3b/303f34ce374a43374b30477de3f9945bdb4b.pdf) makes a case for interpreting  V as a postmodern anarchist.